# How to center UITableViewCell, constraints are not able to align

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, constraints, cell

I'm not able to align the UITableViewCell, please look at the image [image: below:]

and for some reason I can't align the constraints neither for the cell nor for the UITableView: [image: constraints]

Comment: That might be the default separators.. You can turn it off by using the attributes of the table view on the xib/storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UITableViewCell` always has the same width as its `UITableView`. So you cannot set align constraints to the cell. What you see is the default behavior of a UITableViewCell. The separator line runs to the right side. On the left side there is a margin.

If you want a centered separator line that has a margin on both sides you have to draw it yourself and disable the default separator line.